# ElasticSearch Multi Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I was wondering if it was possible to retrieve the aggregation keys/counters for the documents that are not part of the response. I mean the documents which have been put in the *sum_other_doc_count* field.

My code for the Aggregation is as follow :

```
AggregationBuilder agg = AggregationBuilders.terms("AGG_1").field("field1")
            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("AGG_2").field("field2")
                    .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("AGG_3").field("field3")
                            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("AGG_4").field("field4"))));
```

I've got 5 documents on the AGG_2 that are not part of the response but I need them as much as the others.

```
"AGG_1": {
     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "404",
           "doc_count": 3506,
           "AGG_2": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": "OK",
                    "doc_count": 1206,
                    "AGG_3": {
                       "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                       "sum_other_doc_count": 5,
                       "buckets": [ ...
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a different `size` value for `terms aggregations` to specify how many buckets per do you want to get

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "AGG_1" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "field1",
                "size" : 20 // override the number of buckets to return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try this.

Comment: Is there a way to guess the exact size we should put ? I mean, I didn't know how much data I'll retrieve so...

Comment: It seems not. As a workaround you can get number of distinct values using `cardinality` aggregation but even this value is not guaranteed to be precise https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html

Comment: Thanks for your help!